# Which is best way to implement timer in turn based multiplayer game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, timer

I am implementing multiplayer turn based game using Node.js for server side scripting.
Game is just like **monopoly** where multiple room and single room have multiple players. 
I want to implement timer for all rooms, i have gone through many article, I have two options as follows:

**1}** I will emit with current time to each player at once and they will process timer and emit to server on turn or time up.

**2}** I may manage timer at server and emit at every second but it will create load to server, also confuse as Node.js is **single threaded** then how will i manage multiple **setInterval()** for multiple room. it will add in queue and will create latency.

So please assist me best option.

Answer (score 1):

A hybrid approach may suit best for this problem. You could start, initially, by receiving the current value of the timer from the server. Subsequently, the clients can run the timer down independently without requesting the server for the current time. If accuracy is important to this project, then you can request the server every 15 seconds or so to adjust for time drift that may cause discrepancies between the server and its clients.

Also, note that even though Node.js is single threaded it is nonetheless inherently asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, i can do that but in case accidentally all player goes off or socket disconnect then what should i do? should i create event for that?

Comment: In that case, you can default to rely on the client side timer and ignore the time drift that occurs. Generally, this inaccuracy will only be on the order of milliseconds regardless.

Alternatively, depending on the functionality of the project, you may want to freeze the timer and display a temporary error message indicating a disconnection.

Comment: Yes, that might be possible. I tried with server side but once room increases time works like ghost...

Comment: i can do one thing, manage object of each player and if all are disconnect then i can stop game from server side.

Comment: @YadavChetan have you implemented this yet? I am trying to implement this but what if all players are disconnected, how will the turns keep on moving ?